# Eclipse wont work anymore

Tags: android, eclipse

Starting this morning, if I try to write in the following method using autocomplete code, Eclipse don't suggest nothing.
for example, if I write :

if(view. ..... then the autocomplete code not appear and if I click CTRL + SPACE the eclipse show error :the method must override a superclass method

my JRE is 1.6 already, so I don't know what to do.

Any help?

```
    mAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox1) {
                CheckBox v = (CheckBox) view;
                v.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RecordsList.this);
                v.setTag(id);
                if (selectedRows.contains(String.valueOf(id))) {
                    v.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    v.setChecked(false);
                }

                return true;
            }
```

}

[image]

this happend if I use:

```
mAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    v
    return false;
}
```

});

But if I use the following way, work ok:

```
      mAdapter.setViewBinder(ViewBinder);
  private ViewBinder ViewBinder = new ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
  }
```

}

Comment: clean your project and restart the eclipse.

Comment: switch to intelliJ community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst case scenario, remove the eclipse project and reimport it. If the JDT cache is corrupted, it will be rebuilt.

Comment: Umm, it doesnt seem to work anonymous inner classes. I just checked my eclipse. It is working fine. Which version of eclipse are you using?  Does it not work for any such anonymous inner classes or only for this particular instance?

Comment: After a lot of job with Eclipse annd following your suggestion, I got it work back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Goto

```
Window - > Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist
```

Check if everything is ok

```
Window - > Preferences -> General -> Keys
```

Type "Content Assist", select it from the 'Command" list, and check if "Binding" is Ctrl + Space